# iptables error: "No chain/target/match by that name."

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04

Trying to block a certain http/https URL request from hitting the server by adding this rule to iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports 80,443 -m string --string "my_string" --algo bm -j DROP
```

This returns the following error: `No chain/target/match by that name`

I can add other rules to the INPUT chain no problem.  I believe I've identified the culprit as the string module, but to me the syntax looks fine.

Comment: are you using an standdard ubuntu kernel? Because the syntax is fine.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 server kernel 2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64

Comment: A module is missing, looks at directory modules if you have the modules that you are using in your command line. Your command ran perfect in you of my Ubuntu 10.04 servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are some specific considerations to be taken if you want to properly setup iptables on an openvz vps, take a look at the official openvz wiki : http://wiki.openvz.org/Setting_up_an_iptables_firewall